# Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. Rvest scraping

Tags: r, for-loop, rvest

I know I have some problems with my for loop, but need somebody to spot where the problem is.

These are two pages I would like to scrape 100 links in each. Notice you need credentials to get in there. But I write them here just to see all the code:

```
urls <- c("http://cli.linksynergy.com/cli/publisher/links/linkfinder.php?mode=basic&keyword=linux&exact=&any=&exclude=&mid=-1&cat=&sort=&retailprice_sort=&productname_sort=&shortdesp_sort=&categoryname_sort=&keyword_sort=&linklang=pt_BR&currec=1&max=100",
"http://cli.linksynergy.com/cli/publisher/links/linkfinder.php?mode=basic&keyword=linux&exact=&any=&exclude=&mid=-1&cat=&sort=&retailprice_sort=&productname_sort=&shortdesp_sort=&categoryname_sort=&keyword_sort=&linklang=pt_BR&currec=101&max=100")
```

I use `rvest` package to scrape them. This is the for loop:

```
enlaces <- vector("character", length = length(urls))

for(i in seq_along(urls)){
  Sys.sleep(1)
  derby <- read_html(jump_to(session, urls[i]))
  enlaces[i] <- derby %>%
    html_nodes(".td_auto_left a:nth-child(1)") %>% 
    html_attr('href')
}
```

Ideally, I will get a vector composed of 200 links, 100 links scraped for each of the links stored in `urls`.

However, I get the error `Number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

I think that the problem might be that `enlaces` expect only one object in each iteration. However it creates 100 and don't know how to proceed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my question by creating a `list` instead than a `vector`, and with double brackets in the `for` loop.

```
enlaces <- list()

for(i in seq_along(urls)){
  Sys.sleep(1)
  derby <- read_html(jump_to(session, urls[i]))
  enlaces[[i]] <- derby %>%
    html_nodes(".td_auto_left a:nth-child(1)") %>% 
    html_attr('href')
}
```